# Trouble with function pointers in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm having a very hard time finding the problem in my code. I'm trying to pass a function pointer to the GPU to be executed by the kernel, but for some reason it all fails. Here's my declaration:

```
typedef void* (*map_func)(void* p);

__device__ void* f(void* param)
{
    int value = (intptr_t)param;
    return (void*)(value * value * value);
}

__device__ map_func d_map = f;
```

Notice the assignment of `f`. This is to prove that calling the function pointer with a device function works.

In the kernel I'm calling `d_map`. On the host I'm declaring and copying a function pointer:

```
void* square(void* param)
{
    int value = (intptr_t)param;
    return (void*)(value * value);
}

...

map_func h_map = square;    
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_map, &h_map, sizeof(map_func));
```

However, when actually executing the kernel, I get `unspecified launch failure`, which I suspect means a segfault. I've tested the return code of `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` and it is success.

**In summary**: calling `d_map` if it's pointing to a device function works, but if I try to copy a host function it fails.

I'm sure it's some stupid mistake that I'm unable to spot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that you're not dereferencing `param`, you probably want `int value = *(intptr_t)param;` unless the int value is the value of the pointer itself, in which case you want `int value = (int)param;`

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because in the current version it works fine, but using both the versions suggested (which I actually did before this one) the code does not compile with gcc. In the first version it says that "operand of * must be a pointer", while in the second one, "cast from `void*` to `int` loses precision".

Comment: What type is `intptr_t`, `int*` right?

Comment: I have not done this kind of stuff before, but why do you have d_map and &h_map ? Is that the api ? or did you forget an & before d_map or incude it by mistake before h_map ?

Comment: Your square is a host function right? Are you trying to copy host function to the device?

Comment: @Pavan: No luck I'm afraid. Passing it as a string has the same effect. :(

Comment: @Tudor, Are you trying to launch host function on your device?

Comment: @Tudor, I thought you could only execute device or global on the device.

Comment: @Tudor, Also, the function pointer size on the device may be different from the one on host. You could be copying more memory than allocated.

Comment: @Camford: I see what you mean... and the more I think about it, the more it seems that what I'm trying to do is not possible. :(

Comment: @Tudor, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Camford: I'm trying to somehow dynamically pass a piece of code to be executed on the GPU, but I guess that if it's not compiled as a device function, there's no way that can work.

Comment: @Tudor, I am pretty sure you can't dynamically pass a device function (unless they added the feature in 4.1 which I don't think they did).

Comment: Yes, you can't call a host function from device code, whether it's a function pointer or not.  Unless you are JIT compiling the code you want to call on the device, there's no reason why you couldn't just define __device__ versions of the code you want to call on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just occured to me, it may worth a try. Declare the functions you want to be passed around as device functions. Give each of them a device function pointer like you've done for `f`. Call

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_map, &<function of choice>, sizeof(d_map), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)
```

Since you are copying memory allocated on your device, the function pointer size should hopefully match.

This is completely untested. It may kill your card.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately compilation fails saying that the second parameter (address of device function) does not match the signature of `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.

Comment: Hmm... oh well. I don't have a setup to compile the code with at the moment. Another thing you can try is to use a `__global__` function to do the selection.

Comment: Well, I did eventually manage to do what you suggested, but in a more convoluted way and I ended up having the `d_map` as a parameter to the kernel. Thanks anyway.